# Vanity URLs with .htaccess and PHP?

Tags: htaccess, php, redirects, url, apache

I need to create a vanity URL redirect using htaccess and PHP.

My requirements are:

If a user writes `example.com/users/foobar`
The client will be redirected to for example:
`profile.php?user=foobar` in either the */users/* directory or the root directory. Possibly in an */inc/* folder in the root directory.

A `example.com` to `www.example.com` redirect is also necessary.
The URL needs to stay same visually. I would like all of this in a single *.htaccess* file.

Optional:

I would also like (although not a requirement) the redirect to **also** be applied on `example.com/foobar`

I have not found any answers that does this.

Comment: Why would you want to convent `/users/username/` into `profile.php?user=username` the first example looks better and will help your committed members remember their URL easier, just saying...

Comment: @SimonHayter I assume the OP really means an "internal rewrite", as otherwise I agree, "The client will be redirected" doesn't appear to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: "Possibly in an /inc/ folder in the root" - "possibly"? Yes or no?

Answer (score 2):

First off the easiest one for www is this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now for some actual rewriting you should be able to use something like this.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(users)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$2 [L]
```

But to be honest, in my experience your best bet is just to try for yourself and create for your specific needs. If you don't create it for yourself and just go copy pasting, any minor change you will need and you will get in trouble. There is enough of examples and explanations just through google or checking other questions here on [stackexchange.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess)

Comment: Shouldn't the last `RewriteRule` be more specific? eg. `RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]`